# Logging output into Database

Tags: java, spring, logging, persistence

I am developing a middleware application using Java, Spring, Hibernate, slf4j, log4j, Oracle db stack. Currently I log output to text file. I want to store logs in database for troubleshooting purpose. I tried using log4j db appender to directly log into db but I found the performance to be too slow. So now instead I let log4j append to a file and in a separate thread I read the log file line by line and insert into database. This method is not too slow and also it does not affect the performance of main application.

My question is, does anyone else have a better idea or is there a better way to do it ? I dont want to use any tools like loggy or splunk, because for my purpose those tools are an overkill. I want to know of any homegrown techniques I can use.

Comment: Just a follow up. I ended up writing my own log reader to read the files and insert useful information into the database.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have said you don't want to use external tools but I think that is a mistake. The effort you are putting in to create a bespoke solution for your logging has already be made by others and will provide a better more efficient and robust solution than you can.

For starters, loading the log files into the database simply to make them more searchable is a bad idea. You then have the performance overhead of running the database and loading all the files in, plus having to write and test all your code to do this.

I would recommend looking at the logstash tool.

If you are determined to go with your solution of loading then to a database then you need to provide some information on what type of database you intend to use.

Comment: I use Oracle db for storing the log. Meanwhile, I will take a look at logstash tool. thanks.

Comment: I wanted to update here that I ended up using Logstash server for this. My Org already had a Logstash server setup and I just need to configure the log file locations.